# Persist model field from GET to POST

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, parameters, model

In the controller's GET method, I pick up a parameter (id) from the query string and assign it to a property in the model, which then gets sent to the view.

The view contains a form in which the user will supply the rest of the values for this model.  When the model then gets sent back to the POST method, I need that original parameter (id) back again.  But I'm not sure how to persist it.  In the POST method, the id field is coming back blank. Is there a better way to do this?

```
    // GET: CreateInsured
    [Route("Home/CreateInsured/{id}")]
    public ActionResult CreateInsured(int id)
    {
        Insured insured = new Insured();
        insured.PolicyId = id;
        return View(insured);
    }

    // POST: CreateInsured
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult CreateInsured(Insured insured)
    {
       //insured.PolicyId is empty
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put this Id into a `Hidden` field, like this:

`@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.PolicyId)`

And this field should be into your form.